# Unpack vertices' properties returned from a select()

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I would like to write a **MATCH query** in gremlin to find a subgraph matching a particular pattern. The pattern of interest contains 4 different types/labels of nodes: **c, p, r,** and **s**. And 4 different types of edges as shown below:

```
(c)->[affecting]->(p)
(c)-[c_found_in_release]->(r)
(p)-[p_found_in_release]->(r)
(s)-[severity]->(c)
```

So far I have the query below which works fine, however, the results do not show the properties of the vertices returned. Since the verticies returned from the `select()` statement belong to different types of nodes, I cannot use something like `value()` or `valueMap()`

```
    g.V().match(
            __.as('c').out('affecting').as('p'), \
            __.as('c').out('cve_found_in_release').as('r'), \
            __.as('p').out('pack_found_in_release').as('r'), \
            __.as('s').both('severity').as('c') \
    ). \
    select('c', 'p', 'r', 's').limit(10)
```

- Current result:

```
    ==>[c:v[0],p:v[3],r:v[6],s:v[10]]
```

How to get something more detailed like this instead:

- Desired result:

```
==>[
        c:[cve_id:[CVE-2021-3618],publishedOn:[2022-03-23],
        p:[name:[vsftpd],version:[3.0.3]],
        r:[sourceBranch:[1.0],detectedOn:[2022-04-05],status:[Upgraded]],
        s:[severity:[High]],
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add additional by() modulators. On the Tinkergraph modern example graph:

```
g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
g.V().match(
  __.as('v').hasLabel('software').as('s'),
  __.as('s').both().hasLabel('person').as('p')
).select('s', 'p')
  .by(values('name', 'lang').fold())
  .by(values('name', 'age').fold())
==>[s:[lop,java],p:[marko,29]]
==>[s:[lop,java],p:[josh,32]]
==>[s:[lop,java],p:[peter,35]]
==>[s:[ripple,java],p:[josh,32]]
```